# LDAP Configuration

Tags: active-directory, ldap, file-sharing

I'm installing server 2012. I've two printer that need to contact my AD to retrieve users name, password and users share folder for scan. the printer should made a request via LDAP. I've create an this is the structure a setup in AD.
OU=Users,OU=Association Users,DC=MyDomain,DC=com
OU=direction,OU=Association Users,DC=MyDomain,DC=com
can someone can explain how to setup my ldap
second
I also create a shared folder

```
D:\Users
 | Home      -> ShareName Home$
 |    User1
 |    User2
 | Profiles  -> ShareName Profiles$
 |    User1
 |    User2
```

I configured so that even the administrator does not have access to directory users. I would like to know how to solve this problem
thank's

Comment: Could you please clarify what your problem is?

Comment: @Damien, as you see the schema, i create folders d:\users\home and d:\users\profiles. after a fill users info in AD(home: \\SERVER\Home$\%username% and profile:\\SERVER\Profiles$\%username%) then the system create the subfolder user1 and user2. i log with user1 and user2, the system create in profiles directory user1.v2 and user2.v2. i can't get in user1, user2, user1.v2 and user2.v2 when i log with administrator account.

Comment: @Damien, for the second problem, we get 2 RISO printer i call the RISO technical center and ask them how can i register user in the printer they told me that i have to create and configure a ldap server. theh printer will connect to the server and retrieve users of my active directory. i read on many forum than in server 2012 ldap is installed by default on the system. i don't know how to

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but any comment I make here could be interpreted incorrectly, and it sounds like you are doing this all in a live production environment. I would suggest you get yourself on an Active Directory training course and build a test environment. The nature of your questions would also be better suited to the "server fault" site.